# With findHomography, how to improve the quality of a match and avoid duplicates?

Tags: opencv, ransac

I use OpenCV for object recognition.
Once I have the list of `keypoints` for the scene image and the template image, I use the `findHomography` function with RANSAC.
There can be several identical objects in one scene, so I run the function against the scene's list until it can't find a valid homography anymore. After every iteration, I remove the matched `keypoints` from the scene list.

Very often, I have more than one detection per object and the quality of subsequent detections lowers gradually.

My understanding is that RANSAC only uses a few of all good keypoints during an iteration and has still enough keypoints left for another detection.

Is there a way to force it to use all matching keypoints?
Or, once an homography is found, search for other fitting keypoints and then recompute the homography using the *regular method*?
This should produce more accurate results, as more information is available to calculate the homography. Also, there would not be duplicates anymore.

**Edit:**

Here's an example of [the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my4Rl.png) I get, created with [this template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9sHC.png).
I don't care about the poor fits. My question is about the double detection (indicated with an arrow).

[image: Result]

Comment: I think the core of RANSAC is to do random sampling of all the points, if you want to use all the keypoints, then you are not using RANSAC anymore.

Comment: Can you please post an example picture? There's a huge problem with this approach; if you have say a template image and you have a scene with 10 of those templates inside it, then you may be matching some of the features with the first template, some of them with the second template, and so on, which would not warp your image properly.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds: I edited my question, adding an example of double detection.